# intervening Android Install-time Permission granting mechanism

Tags: android, installation

I'm new in Android. I have an Idea to enrich user's knowledge whilst installing a desired application.
the idea is developing an application that can analyze .apk file of the application to check if it's over-privileged or not. and inform the user if this application which he's trying to install is over-privileged or not.
but since there's already a mechanism from Android which asks user's consent to grant whatever permission the application requests, I'm not sure if my application can somehow intervene this mechanism, postpone it, pause it or it can not.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if my application can somehow intervene this mechanism, postpone it, pause it

None of these are possible, sorry. You are welcome to create your own custom firmware that has this feature, but you cannot create this capability via an SDK application, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: so is there any guideline to create such a firmware?

Comment: @user1064786: I do not know what you mean by "guideline".

Answer (score 0):

I am not far from where you are ~ the entire mechanization you seek is based on an xml file in the "root" of the installation - it is called **AndroidManifest.xml** = all permission based issues should begin original first efforts on that file:
[The AndroidManifest.xml File](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

> Every application must have an AndroidManifest.xml file (with precisely that name) in its root directory. The manifest presents essential information about the application to the Android system, information the system must have before it can run any of the application's code. Among other things, the manifest does the following: .....

the "app-store" web based distribution system is supposed to pick that up and not only make some decisions on what to present to the user but as well differentiate to some extent what to do in the matter but as I just got a Droid-X emulator available in my installation I can tell you for a fact that "versioning" is subject to oversimplification as we cannot rely on users being tech-geeks

Comment: sry, you mean Android market is doing this itself? I don't think so! then, do you think there is a way to play with package manager to modify it's own permission granting mechanism? my idea was telling user which this application is over-privileged and may harm your security/privacy. this is not what Android does right now; it only asks user if he wishes to grant permission to the app or not, but it doesn't clarify user if app could be malicious, over-privileged or not